# IOS Live Activity Token expires

Tags: node.js, swift, google-cloud-functions

I am sending live activity updates using NodeJS and Firebase Functions. After some time the device token that I receive from this function expires.

```
Task {
           for await data in activity.pushTokenUpdates {
              let myToken = data.map {String(format: "%02x", $0)}.joined()
              // Keep this myToken for sending push notifications
               firebaseRealtimeDB.setLiveActivityToken(pushToken: myToken, eventId: event.id ?? 0)
               print("eventid", event.id ?? 0)
               print("pushToken", myToken)
           }
        }
```

The error code I get from NodeJS is this one: The server says: {"reason":"ExpiredToken","timestamp":1709872372000}. It is a 410 error code that says the [device token is expired](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/handling-notification-responses-from-apns). This happens if the live activity is active for about 6 hours, even though it gets updated constantly. How can I prevent the token from expiring?

The function I use to update the live activities from Cloud Functions looks like this:

```
function updateLiveActivityEvent(event, pushToken, authFile) {


    var deviceToken = pushToken;

   const secondsSinceEpoch = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
   var payload = {
       iss: 'X',
       iat: secondsSinceEpoch
    }
   var finalEncryptToken = jwt.sign(payload, authFile, {algorithm: 'ES256', keyid: 'X'});
   const session = http2.connect('https://api.push.apple.com:443/3/device/' + deviceToken);

    const body = {
        "aps": {
        "timestamp": secondsSinceEpoch,
        "event": "update",
        "content-state": {
                "event" : event
            }
    }
    };
    functions.logger.log("token:", finalEncryptToken);

    var buffer = new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(body));

    const x = session.request({
    ":method": "POST",
    ":path": "/3/device/" + deviceToken,
    "authorization": "bearer " + finalEncryptToken,
    "apns-push-type": "liveactivity",
    "apns-priority": "10",
    "apns-topic": "X.push-type.liveactivity",
    "Content-Type": 'application/json',
    "Content-Length": buffer.length
    });

    functions.logger.log()
    x.on('response', (headers) => {
    console.log(headers[http2.constants.HTTP2_HEADER_STATUS]);
    });
    let data = '';
    x.setEncoding('utf8');
    x.on('data', (chunk) => data += chunk);
    x.on('end', () => {
        console.log(`The server says: ${data}`);

    });
    x.end(JSON.stringify(body));

  };
```

Comment: Somewhere in the documentation it says that the max is 8 hours. I don’t remember where but Apple has a limit.